# Event Listener in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, embedded, event-listener

I'm preparing myself to make a robot. This robot has a route planner that generates a list of commands that dictate movement (go forward, turn right, etc.), and must execute each step consecutively. It will have proximity sensors that will notify the robot when there's an obstacle ahead and it has to reroute. I'm using generator functions and dummy lambda functions as the following code shows:

```
import time
import threading as thr

class Tester():
    def __init__(self):
        self.toDo = [lambda: self.display_with_lag("a"),
                     lambda: self.display_with_lag("b"),
                     lambda: self.display_with_lag("c")]

    def display_with_lag(self, arg):
        print("wait...")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("the value is %s" % arg)
    
    def step(self):
        while True:
            try:
                print("You're performing a step")
                self.toDo[0]()
                del self.toDo[0]
                yield self.toDo[0]
            except Exception:
                print("Either there was an error or it's over, doesn't matter as of now")
                break
    
    def execute(self):
        orders = self.step()
        while True:
            try:
                next(orders)
            except StopIteration:
                break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Tester()    
    executer = thr.Thread(target=test.execute)
    executer.start()
```

`display_with_lag()` would be my robot movements and they'd be added to `toDo` separately from `__init__()` as you'd expect.

I know threading is unnecesary as of now, but now I want to add an event listener of sorts, that if I press a certain keystroke at any time it will stop whatever it's doing, erase `test.toDo`, append new functions to it, and return to running `test.execute()` with the changes made to `test.toDo`. This would simulate my proximity sensor. I'm planning on using a RPi and connect the sensor to a pin and from what I've read GPIO includes a functionality like what I want but I don't know how to use it, and if it's possible I'd love to also know the general, python way.

Comment: You may need a event-framework, such as signal-slots in PyQt